# How to restart network from parachain data that was left on the disk?

Tags: parachain, kusama, parachain-collator

I am trying to restart our network using data left by previous collators. How do I apply that data to start a new ( or the same ) network without losing data? I am looking for a solution similar polkashot for kusama.

Answer (score 1):

Boot with `--base-dir <PREVIOUS COLLATOR DATA PATH>` or `-d <PREVIOUS COLLATOR DATA PATH>`.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from pointing your node to use the db dir of your previous collator keep in mind that you can also use `export-state` subcommand to generate a chainspec based on that db state, and from there you can generate genesis wasm and genesis state if needed.

Comment: The export-state produces a chain specs that do not have your orignal collator set. How to get my orignal collator set back, as export-state produces a raw chain specs and we can not add our collator in this raw chain specs as we do in plain chain specs. Can I solve this issues without using "fork_of_substrate"